# Meaning of "hot questions" index?

Tags: discussion, design

What is the meaning of the numbers in the leftmost column: $94$, $70$, $54$, ...?
Uncharacteristically, neither hovering nor clicking reveals the meaning.

---

[image]

Comment: Interesting that MSE is (at least temporarily) dominating the "hot questions" list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer can be found here:[How do the "arbitrary hotness points" work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page), and in the question linked to on that page: [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions). It takes a reddit-type formula (taking logs of scores) and divides it by its age, with quite a few other things thrown in.

It has it's opponents:[Don't display arbitrary hotness points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101369/dont-display-arbitrary-hotness-points?lq=1).

Comment: Thanks, Brian, for the thorough answer!